# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid·Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction:

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have this after_save method that runs to ensure that this current address object is the only address that is active under that user.

```
before_save ensure_one_active_address

def ensure_one_active_address
  Address.where("active = ? AND user_id = ? AND id NOT IN (?)", active, user_id, id).update_all(active: 0) if active
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid·Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

I can't reproduce the error, only happens in production. I understand what the error means, but I don't understand where it's happening. Is the update_all happening before the where query can finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use this callback, you should use `after_commit` instead of `after_save`.

Comment: I'm not finding `after_transaction` on the docs. I should have mentioned that i'm on 3.2

Are you referring to `after_commit`?
I'm getting the hint that `after_save` means i'm still within the save transaction when i'm running this query?

Comment: I found this, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks

Comment: `after_commit  :ensure_one_active_address` did the trick. thanks!!

Comment: Yep sorry, the correct name is indeed after_commit :)